# How do I share internet connection in Synology Diskstation?

Tags: internet-connection, internet-sharing, synology-diskstation

My Synology Diskstation has 2 LAN ports.

LAN 1 is directly connected to my laptop's LAN port. (IP Address 169.*.*.*)

LAN 2 is connected to the home router with internet. (IP Address 192.168.*.*)

How can my laptop get access to internet in this setup?

Comment: I don't have access to a Synology any more but I don't think its possible. Look in the manual for your model and if it is do-able it will say so. As a side note, you can get a 4 port gigabit switch for about $15 and that would simplify this matter significantly.

Comment: @Larryc, I prefer not to buy yet another device to plug. Apart from it occupies space, it consumes additional power. I'd take that as my last option. Thanks though for trying to help.